# Duplicate and transition to ipad, is it universal app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am having an iPhone application and i want to make it compatible with iPad so what i did is that I went to project->Target->Right Click->Duplicate->Duplicate and Transition to iPad so i got nib files for iPad, i set the views according to iPad resolution. So my this app is working on iPad as well as iPhone my question is that i am having two targets in my project and i have to build two separate builds for iPhone and iPad. I think it is not universal app is it? If it is or not should i have to have separate App ID for iPhone and iPad application to put it on App store ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the publishing on the App Store part, but in the company where I work each time we make an universal app for a client we have just one target, one project and one ipa.

Based on the device's type (iPad or iPhone) we then load different files and/or nibs.
For example, if you select your target, you have the Universal option for the Devices field. Choosing it lets you specify different  interfaces for each device. The we load different module for each device or use general modules with different nibs.